# Creating HTML table with vertically oriented text as table header

Tags: html, css, vertical-text

I would like to create a HTML table with vertically written text as header (i.e. header text is rotated 90 degrees). I am using the flollowing style

```
<th style="-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); writing-mode:tb-rl; -moz-transform:rotate(90deg); -o-transform: rotate(90deg); white-space:nowrap; display:blocking; padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px; " align="left"  id="#COLUMN_HEADER_NAME#">#COLUMN_HEADER#</th>
```

In MS IE 9.x is displays OK. In Firefox and Chrome the header seems to float over the top of the table, it overlaps with the table rows below it. can somebody please help? I simple have no idea why is this happening. I started out with this tutorial: http://scottgale.com/blog/css-vertical-text/2010/03/01/

TIA, Tamas

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't believe you can get the height of the `<th>` to change when rotating it's contents with CSS alone. Below is how I do this with a bit of jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/tsYRQ/1004/

Comment: Doesn't work with Safari, I don't manage to make the columns thin.

Comment: This [fiddle fork](http://jsfiddle.net/p2FEY/) will work for Firefox (-moz-transform), and also reduces the width of the header to a proper size.

Comment: A lot has happened in the 3 years since this was first answered. Looks like the `writing-mode` style is now supported by FF and conflicts with the `transform`.

Answer (score 6):

From http://blog.petermares.com/2010/10/27/vertical-text-in-html-table-headers-for-webkitmozilla-browsers-without-using-images/

Using CSS to rotate an element (e.g. a `<div>`) within a `<td>` element causes the column width to shrink to just accomodate the rotated text - however the row height does not grow as needed.

Works in Chrome and Safari on Mac (for me at least).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            th
            {
                background-color: grey;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: bottom;
                height: 150px;
                padding-bottom: 3px;
                padding-left: 5px;
                padding-right: 5px;
            }

            .verticalText
            {
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                width: 20px;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                padding-left: 3px;
                padding-right: 3px;
                padding-top: 10px;
                white-space: nowrap;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
                -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);                 
            };
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th><div class="verticalText">Column 2</div></th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
                <th><div class="verticalText">Column 4</div></th>
                <th>Column 5</th>
                <th><div class="verticalText">Column 6</div></th>
                <th>Column 7</th>
                <th><div class="verticalText">Column 8</div></th>
                <th>Column 9</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue with this is that you're setting a static height on the `th` style of `150px`. Look at all the extra whitespace, even above your vertical-text columns: http://jsfiddle.net/2xP5C/ This is why I prefer using jQuery, since it will set the height to be only as tall as is needed to fit the longest bit of text.

Comment: You're right - I mistakenly thought the row height was adjusting but I was just being careless!
Looks like a hybrid of the two answers could give the best result...?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an easier way to get vertical text in table cell:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        td {
        text-align: center;
        }
        /*Creation of vertical text in cell*/
        .vertical_Text {

                display: block;
                color: #f00;

                -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
                -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);                 
            };
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="20">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- vertical cell -->
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="vertical_Text" title="vertical text">HEAD</span></td>
            <td>header1-2</td>
            <td colspan="3">header1-2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>header2-1</td>
            <td>header2-2</td>
            <td>header2-3</td>
            <td>header2-4</td>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <!-- tr*5>td{data-$/$$}*5 -->
        <tr>
            <!-- vertical cell -->
            <td rowspan="5"><span  class="vertical_Text" title="vertical text">DATA</span></td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works just for data from showed example, but longer caption instead HEAD ruined table, fall of teble

Answer (score 0):

simply you can do it with CSS

```
table th {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
table th {
    font-size: .85em;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
    text-align: right;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work with Safari (Desktop and iOS)