# Rotated text inside rowspaned cell and word wrap

Tags: html, css, rotation, word-wrap

*Summary:* My 90-degrees rotated text, put into rowspaned cell, is word-wrapped to two lines, though in my opinion, there is enough space in cell to write it in a single line. Is this some kind of browsers' bug?

*Details:* I have a single-one text, that I [rotate 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15807121/1469208):

```
.rotate-90-degrees
{
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);  /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)"; /* IE8 */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* IE9+ */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Safari 3.1+, Chrome */
    transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Standard */
}
```

I then put it into a table cell, rowspaned to four rows:

```
<td rowspan="4">                            
    <div class="rotate-90-degrees">
        Quest. no 1
    </div>
</td>
```

Browser (Chrome) renders div itself as `44px x 40 px`, while table cell's as `61px x 148px` with `padding` set to `8px`. Though, I was pretty sure, that I'll get entire text in a single line, it is word-wrapped to two lines and produces quite ugly effect:

[image]

It seems, that there is enough space to write it in a single line. `44px` div's width (which now becomes height, due to rotation) plus 2 x `8px` padding is only `60px`, which is still far, far less than cell's height set to `148 px`. Why, then, it is being word-wrapped?

When I highlight cell (second on image) with Chrome Developers Tools, it seems to me, that browser is adding an enormous height padding to cell's content, completely ignoring CSS-set padding (`8px`). Or is there any other reason, that I just don't see?

I tried to "fix" this, by changing padding to `0 px` or even negative value, but without any luck. Is there any way, that I can force browser to render this text in a single line, if there is space enough to fit it?

*BTW:* Tests and examples are made in Chrome, but effect in IE and Firefox is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preventing wrapping in CSS is just:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

(Other [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) may also be useful.)