# Rotate text in table cell

Tags: c#, html, css

I want to show the vertical text in the row header of my table.
I have written  following code

```
 lbHeader.Style.Add("writing-mode", "tb-rl");
 lbHeader.Style.Add("filter", "flipv fliph");
```

It's working on IE9 but not in IE10.

```
I tried –ms-transform : rotate(270deg)
```

And origin property but it is giving alignment issue.

Please suggest something which will work on all versions of IE
And alignment of this text will be center.

Comment: Maybe this help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806925/how-to-rotate-text-left-90-degree-and-cell-size-is-adjusted-according-to-text-in

Answer (score 0):

Try use only: `transform: rotate(270deg)`.

`-ms-transform` is only for IE 9.

If you have problem with CSS visit this web site: [The Cross-Browser CSS3 Rule Generator](http://css3please.com/)