# Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.5 vertical nav-tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tabs

i'm searching for an easy way to get the nav-tabs of **Bootstrap v4** to be vertical (right or left),
pretty much same as [this](https://github.com/dbtek/bootstrap-vertical-tabs).

every library or plugin i found are able to do this only on bootstrap's V3 and not V4.

Comment: You can rotate it to 90 degree. Here is a simple mthod
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806925/how-to-rotate-text-left-90-degree-and-cell-size-is-adjusted-according-to-text-in

Answer (score 0):

In the `<ul>` element, change the `flex direction` from `row` to `column` (it's `row` by default). Here's an example from a website I recently designed in Bootstrap 4 Beta 2. Should work just fine in alpha.

```css
.navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: column;
}
```