# How could I rotate table header cells and automatically adjust to content size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The table I am trying to design is going to end up to be somewhat dynamic. I would like the table header cells to appear rotated (to save horizontal space). I am aware there might be better methods to save some table space, but as I was playing around with some HTML, I got interested in something that seemed quite impossible.

Within following piece of code I tried to rotate the cells:

```css
th {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 100px;/* <-- Anything I could do here? */
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="rotate">
        Foo
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        Bar
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Foo collection
      </td>
      <td>
        Bar collection
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I found some [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806925/how-to-rotate-text-left-90-degree-and-cell-size-is-adjusted-according-to-text-in) in a couple other questions in order to address my issue(s), however most of these questions do not address the issue(s) I am having:

Whenever given table cell's content would increase (e.g. more characters and/or words), content would flow either outside of the given cell or break the appearance of the cell.

First off I would like my table cells to stay where they are supposed to (so no hovering over other cells like what is happening in my fiddle above):

[image: Example table #1]

and secondly I would like to be able to adjust the text inside these cells, meaning that the cells must be able to resize without breaking the table's layout:

[image: Example table #2]

In other words: I would like to create rotated table header cells without losing any of HTML's table default functionalities. Is it possible to rotate a table header cell (`<th>` element) without breaking the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to change the write direction of the text, you can use `writing-mode`. In this case I use `writing-mode: vertical-lr;`, which makes the text vertical, and the container height will change to fit the text. We also need to rotate the text in place, but in the future I would use `sideways-lr`, which lacks support now.

```css
th {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.rotate span {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="rotate">
        <span>Foo</span>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <span>Foo Bar Bazz</span>
      </th>
      <th class="rotate">
        <span>FooBar</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Foo collection
      </td>
      <td>
        Foo Bar Bazz collection
      </td>
      <td>
        Foo Bar collection
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As [noted by @AlRo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905372/how-could-i-rotate-table-header-cells-and-automatically-adjust-to-content-size/56905640?noredirect=1#comment125826251_56905640), you need the `span` to center the text horizontally in Firefox.

Comment: One problem though: If a `<th>` table header contains multiple words, the order of words appearing shows incorrect (due to the `transform: rotate(180deg)`) (e.g. if it contains the words "foo bar" it will display as "bar foo" instead).Would you happen to know how I could fix this?

Comment: It's not caused by the rotation. The cause is the way the `write-mode: vertical-lr;` is rendered. You can change the direction with `vertical-rl`. (see updated answer).

Comment: note that for this to work right on both firefox and webkit the span you included is required. It's easy to miss that as a required step so I think it's worth calling out. on webkit you can just rotate the td or th and it centers it properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to change them dynamically then create a CSS class and add:

```
.rotate-text {
    //for old browsers
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) ;
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) ;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) ;
    //for all modern browsers
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Now use jQuery to check if number of words increased the target, if true toggle the class created above inside your TD or TH

```
jQuery("th").toggleClass("rotate-text");
```

I hope this helps you.