# Table headers that are rotated vertically, aligned center+bottom, cross-browser

Tags: html, css

I have table with rotated headers that look as-desired in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

##### Chrome v108 (vertical-bottom, horizontal-middle) ✅

[image: headers are rotated vertically, vertically bottom-aligned and horizontally centered]

##### Firefox v107 (vertical-middle, horizontal-right) ❌

[image: headers are rotated vertically, but vertically middle-aligned and horizontally right aligned]

How can I make them work cross-browser so that they are rotated vertically, vertically bottom of the cell, horizontally centered, and take up a minimum of width?

Code I'm using is slightly modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47245068) to get it working in Chrome:

```css
table { border-collapse:collapse; font-family:sans-serif }
thead th {
    /* Rotate vertical: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47245068 */
    -ms-writing-mode:tb-rl;
    -webkit-writing-mode:vertical-lr;
    writing-mode:vertical-rl;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0.5em 0 0 0;
    opacity:0.5;
    font-size:90%;
}
tbody th { text-align:right; padding-right:0.5em }
tbody td { text-align:center; padding:0 0.2em }
.yes { font-weight:bold; color:#060 }
.maybe { color:#440 }
.no  { color:#500 }
```

```html
<table><thead><tr>
    <th></th>
    <th class="yes">yes</th>
    <th class="maybe">maybe</th>
    <th class="no">no</th>
    <th>who?</th>
</tr></thead><tbody><tr>
    <th>Fri, Dec 9, 12pm</th>
    <td class="yes">2</td><td class="maybe">1</td><td class="no">1</td>
    <td><button>≡</button></td>
</tr><tr>
    <th>Wed, Dec 14, 12pm</th>
    <td class="yes">4</td><td class="maybe">0</td><td class="no">0</td>
    <td><button>≡</button></td>
</tr><tr>
    <th>Fri, Dec 16, 12pm</th>
    <td class="yes">0</td><td class="maybe">0</td><td class="no">1</td>
    <td><button>≡</button></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Follow-on question: which browser is rendering contrary to specification in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me, tested on Chrome, Firefox, and iOS Safari:

```css
thead th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align:     center;
  width:          0.5em;
  min-width:      0.5em;
  padding:        0;
}
thead th span {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform:    rotate(180deg);

  /* slight horizontal offset to suit tastes */
  position:relative; left:-2px;
}

/* need following (or explicit width) or else the */
/* cells in the rows will force wrap every word   */
tbody th { white-space:nowrap }

/*************** unrelated formatting ***************/
table { border-collapse:collapse; margin:1em auto }
thead th { font-size:90% }
thead th span { opacity:0.5 }
th, td { vertical-align:middle; padding:0 0.5em }
th { text-align:right; font-weight:normal }

.yes { color:#090; font-weight:bold }
.maybe { color:#660 }
.no  { color:#600 }

tr > * { border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2)}
tr:last-child > * { border-bottom: 0 }
```

```html
<table><thead><tr>
    <th></th>
    <th class="yes"><span>yes</span></th>
    <th class="maybe"><span>maybe</span></th>
    <th class="no"><span>no</span></th>
    <th><span>who?</span></th>
</tr></thead><tbody><tr>
    <th>Fri, Dec 9, 12pm</th>
    <td class="yes">2</td><td class="maybe">1</td><td class="no">1</td>
    <td><button>≡</button></td>
</tr><tr>
    <th>Wed, Dec 14, 12pm</th>
    <td class="yes">4</td><td class="maybe">0</td><td class="no">0</td>
    <td><button>≡</button></td>
</tr><tr>
    <th>Fri, Dec 16, 12pm</th>
    <td class="yes">0</td><td class="maybe">0</td><td class="no">1</td>
    <td><button>≡</button></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```